# Linq JS join syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq, join, left-join

I am trying to join an array of dates and values to an array of dates, without filtering out the extra dates. The LinqJS reference [here](http://neue.cc/reference.htm) is pretty confusing on how I would actually go about using the join. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671667/inner-join-with-linqjs) did not help much either.

**Edit**:

Join documentation here: https://svschmidt.github.io/linqjs/Collection.html#Join

It looks like I need help sorting out how to get the join to be an `outer` and not an `inner` join so it includes null/undefined values.

Say I have two arrays:

**Array 1:**

```
[
'2017-02-10',
'2017-02-11',
'2017-02-12',
'2017-02-13',
'2017-02-20',
'2017-02-21',
'2017-02-22',
'2017-02-23',
'2017-02-24',
'2017-02-25',
'2017-02-26',
'2017-02-27'
]
```

**Array 2:**

```
[
  { date: '2017-02-10', value:  5 },
  { date: '2017-02-12', value:  8 },
  { date: '2017-02-13', value: 13 },
  { date: '2017-02-21', value: 14 },
  { date: '2017-02-24', value: 11 },
  { date: '2017-02-27', value:  7 }
]
```

I want to join them so I get this as my result (`-` for `undefined`):

```
[
'5',
-,
'8',
'13',
-,
'14',
-,
-,
'11',
-,
-,
'7'
]
```

My current syntax:

```
Enumerable.from(array1).join(array2, '$', '$.date', "outer, inner => inner.value").toArray()
```

This results in an array of the values, but the results are still inner joined, and it filters out what might be the `null/undefined` items.

How can I do this? How does the join syntax work for LinqJS?

Comment: You can not join both arrays because their content differs. You can transform them to a final new array though.

Comment: Do you need to use Linq or vanilla js is OK too ?

Comment: I think you mean this library : https://github.com/SvSchmidt/linqjs , I prefer the look of github's readmes ;)

Comment: @MaxZoom Can you explain why that is? I know you can select the keys you wish to join by with LinqJS, I just do not know how.

Comment: First array is array of strings, while the second one contains objects. You need to transform the first array along the structure of the second one.

Comment: @Vovan LinqJS only, I could write out the JS to do it for me, but this is one of those things where I want to figure it out in LinqJs.

Comment: @MaxZoom You can select the key for the 2nd array. `$.date` seems to do that where `$` for the first selector selects the date (string) itself from array1. It already compares the dates from array 1 to the dates property in array 2. But it is doing an inner join which filters the results, and I do not know how to configure the output

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28726394/4454454)

Comment: @niceman https://svschmidt.github.io/linqjs/Collection.html#Join That's helpful! it looks like the issue I'm having is figuring out how to use the `resultSelectorFn` and making sure the join is an `outer` join and not an `inner` join. The description for the `resultSelectorFn` is a bit sparse...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about LinqJS, but regular JS is more than capable of doing this.

There are a couple ways to go about it. The `reduce()`, `map()`, and `sort()` functions are very Linq-esque and work well natively. (There is also `filter()` and a number of others).

```js
const dates = [
'2017-02-10',
'2017-02-11',
'2017-02-12',
'2017-02-13',
'2017-02-20',
'2017-02-21',
'2017-02-22',
'2017-02-23',
'2017-02-24',
'2017-02-25',
'2017-02-26',
'2017-02-27'
]

const data = [
  { date: '2017-02-10', value:  5 },
  { date: '2017-02-12', value:  8 },
  { date: '2017-02-13', value: 13 },
  { date: '2017-02-21', value: 14 },
  { date: '2017-02-24', value: 11 },
  { date: '2017-02-27', value:  7 }
];

const result = dates
  .map(date => ({ date, value: '-' }))
  .concat(data)
  .filter(({ date, value }) => !(data.find(d => d.date === date) && value === '-'))
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime());

console.log(result);

const justValues = Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key].value);

console.log(justValues);
```

Comment: it's good to show that vanilla JS is capable(or at least not as bad as one might think)

Comment: Thanks Sam, however, I am looking for how to use LinqJS. I can write the JS to do just this fairly easily (I already have working code for this issue), but I am more interested in learning how to perform this task with this specific library. This is less of a "`how do I get this result through any means`" question, and more of a "`how do I get this result with this specific framework`" kind of question. If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your comment after I posted my answer.

Comment: All good, I'm sure it will be handy for someone coming here in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`GroupJoin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs#groupjoin)

> Correlates the elements of two sequences based on equality of keys and groups the results. The default equality comparer is used to compare keys.

for a LEFT OUTER JOIN and specify the wanted value and use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs#defaultifempty)

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

with the wanted replacement, if null.

```js
var dates = ['2017-02-10', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21', '2017-02-22', '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-25', '2017-02-26', '2017-02-27'],
    values = [{ date: '2017-02-10', value: 5 }, { date: '2017-02-12', value: 8 }, { date: '2017-02-13', value: 13 }, { date: '2017-02-21', value: 14 }, { date: '2017-02-24', value: 11 }, { date: '2017-02-27', value: 7 }],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(dates)
        .GroupJoin(
            values,
           '',
           '$.date',
           't, u => ({ date: t, value: u.Select("$.value").DefaultIfEmpty("-").ToString() })')
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

ES6

```js
var dates = ['2017-02-10', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21', '2017-02-22', '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-25', '2017-02-26', '2017-02-27'],
    values = [{ date: '2017-02-10', value: 5 }, { date: '2017-02-12', value: 8 }, { date: '2017-02-13', value: 13 }, { date: '2017-02-21', value: 14 }, { date: '2017-02-24', value: 11 }, { date: '2017-02-27', value: 7 }],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(dates)
        .GroupJoin(
            values,
            '',
            '$.date',
            (t, u) => ({
               date: t,
               value: u.Select("$.value").DefaultIfEmpty("-").ToString()
            }))
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```